# Customizing the show page in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

The default show page in ActiveAdmin is a table with one attribute per row. For my backend, this would be fine, except that I want to hide fields such as id, created_at, updated_at.

Is is possible to do that in a way similar to the index page, i.e. by explicitly listing the desired attributes, while letting AtiveAdmin handle the layout?

The only example shown in the docs suggests that to customize the show page you have to completely take over and write a partial or an arbre construct.

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you're looking for attributes_table:

```
show do
  attributes_table :name, :content
end
```

See https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/pages/show.rb if you're curious.

(I completely removed my prior answer because it was basically useless!)

Comment: those links are not working anymore, does someone have alternative links?

Answer (score 2):

```
show do

  attributes_table do
    row :profilepic do
      image_tag admin_user.profilepic.url, class: 'my_image_size'
    end
  row :name
  row :email
  row :adrs
  row :phone
  row :role
  row :salary
  row :parent_id
  row :joindate
end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

This will show an example of an object `Package` with a `has_many` relationship (`FAQS`)

```
  show do |package|
    attributes_table do
      row :slug
      ...
      row :hotel
      panel "FAQS" do
        table_for package.faqs do
          column :question
          column :answer
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

It will be rendered like this:

[image]