# Show altered variable for show page in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Is there a way in ActiveAdmin to edit a variable IE `address` for a controller for the `show` page without having to manually go through and display all fields? I have about 25 fields and would just like to hide the address in the `show` so people without edit access cannot see it.

I know I can customize the show page and list out all the variables but I like the way it looks as is, minus showing the address field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a trick to hide the attributes for the show block like so:

```
show do
  # the array contains the fields to be hidden in the show table
  attributes_table *(AdminUser.column_names.map(&:to_sym) - [:last_sign_in_ip, :sign_in_count])
end
```

modifying the solution [from this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510551/customizing-the-show-page-in-activeadmin) to hide certain fields instead of showing which fields.